# How to transfer leads into queue using workflow

Tags: workflow, process-builder, queue

I want to transfer leads with lead type equals "donot call" transferred into a queue using workflow or process builder. I know there is a provision for mass transfer but I want to automatically transfer leads into queue when a field of 
"donot call" is selected.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Workflow Rules -- have it fire when it is changed to "do not call" and trigger a Field Update and you're set.  Just have it run on the Lead Object, select the "Lead Owner" field and then you can select the correct Queue that you want to assign it to... this is the easiest way to do it :)